# MBP isn't loading Finder, so I need to copy user files from broken computer

Tags: macos, finder

I studied several questions about this issue, but as I don't want to mess anything, I am setting my question as specific as possible,

I have a problematic MBP running macOS. I can boot it, but when the system starts, the screen only shows the cursor. This may be caused by a lack of disk space (I think only 40GB free out of 500).

I can however see my disk from another computer. It's easy to copy my own files, but there are other user accounts on the machine.

Is there a way I can copy (save) these user files as well?

Many thanks.)

Comment: Do you have admin access? Can you start the MBP in Target Disk Mode? If you can do both, you should be able to copy all files.

Comment: I'm now connecting through the Finder on my working machine. Wouldn't I need a special cable to connect these systems.. The MBP is post Firewire..

Comment: You'd need a thunderbolt or FireWire cable to use target disk mode. I think (check before you do this) that you should be able to copy the entire user's home folder (house icon w/ username).

Comment: See my answer here how to do Target Disk Mode: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/265175/connect-a-mac-as-an-external-drive-to-another-mac/265176#265176

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but maybe related & with a potential 'fix' - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264863/security-update-2016-003-10-11-6-issues

Comment: Thanks all for the help. Target Disk Mode worked where, Finder copy did not.